# Using Sled, how do I serialize and deserialize?

Tags: rust, bincode

I'm playing around with the crate [sled](https://crates.io/crates/sled) and attempting a simple serialization and deserialization exercise using [bincode](https://crates.io/crates/bincode) just to get a handle on usage.

While I can get insertion to work, attempting to get a range of results seems more difficult. Here I attempt to put in two records: a key of 42 with the value of "Alice" and a key of 69 with a value of "Bob and then retrieve and print them. I'm having a hard time reconciling deserialization of the vectors that come out:

```rust
use crate::db::Database;
use sled::Db;
use bincode;


pub struct SledDatabase {
    db: Db,
}

impl Database for SledDatabase {
    fn create(&self) {
        // Not handling errors; just an example.
        let key: i64 = 42;
        println!("ser {:?}", bincode::serialize(&key).unwrap());
        self.db.insert(bincode::serialize(&key).unwrap(), bincode::serialize("Alice").unwrap());
        let key2: i64 = 69;
        self.db.insert(bincode::serialize(&key2).unwrap(), bincode::serialize("Bob").unwrap());
    }

    fn query(&self, value : i64) {
        let range = value.to_ne_bytes();
        let mut iter = self.db.range(range..);
        while let Some(item) = iter.next() {
            let (k, v) = item.unwrap();
            println!("res {:?}", k);
            let key: i64 = bincode::deserialize(&k).unwrap();
            let value: String = bincode::deserialize(&v).unwrap();
            println!("age = {}", key);
            println!("name = {}", value);
        }
    }
}

impl SledDatabase {
    pub fn connect() -> SledDatabase {
        // use sled::{ConfigBuilder, Error};
        // let config = ConfigBuilder::new().temporary(true).build();
        SledDatabase { db: Db::open("sled.db").unwrap() }
    }
}
```

Attempting to interact with this using a console entry listener I've pieced together, I get the following output:

```
ser [42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>> 1
res [42]
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Io(Custom { kind: UnexpectedEof, error: "failed to fill whole buffer" })', src/libcore/result.rs:1084:5
```

This occurs on either attempt to deserialize (either the `String` or the `i64` value. Interestingly, the output seems to indicate that either sled or bincode are truncating the key value.

The [examples of sled usage](https://docs.rs/crate/sled/0.28.0) don't seem to address retrieving values, but looking through some documentation and parts of the source, I get the sense that serde serialization is a valid way of getting things in and out of sled.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce this issue with the code given above, I'm unsure if the sled implementation has perhaps changed a size of something related to the range function, and now match the expectations of the code, or if this was just a bug.

None the less, I ran into this error message due to some carelessness on my part.

```
fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let db = sled::open("foo.sled_db").unwrap();
    let codec = bincode::config();

    db.insert("uhoh", codec.serialize(&0)?)?;
    let ser = &db.get("uhoh")?.unwrap();
    let de1: i32 = codec.deserialize(ser)?;
    println!("ok... {}", de1);
    let de2: usize = codec.deserialize(ser)?;
    println!("not ok {}", de2);
}
```

- I've omitted implementations of `From<sled::Error>` and `From<bincode::Error>` for Error, to simplify things.

> ok... 0
>
> Error: Bincode(Io(Custom { kind: UnexpectedEof, error: "failed to fill whole  buffer" })

The thing to note here is that (as you say) value which was serialized is smaller,
than the type we attempt to deserialize into.

```
println!(
       "{} {}",
       core::mem::size_of::<usize>(),
       core::mem::size_of_val(&0)
);

println!(
        "{} {}",
        core::mem::size_of::<usize>(),
        core::mem::size_of::<i32>()
);
```

> 8 4
>
> 8 4

To fix this I serialized this with the value `&0usize` instead of `&0`.
Using serde serialization for sled keys and values indeed does seem fine, but you do need to be careful about the inferred size of values.